# How to check if my .NET Core console app is running as a self-contained app (by running myapp.exe) or if it's running using dotnet myapp.dll?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I've tried using `Environment.CommandLine` to check the executable, but that didn't work, it always shows the dll file. Any idea on how to know if `myapp.exe` file was used to run the app or if `dotnet myapp.dll` was used instead?

Comment: Why do you need to know? For the purposes of usage text or similar?

Comment: @JoeSewell I'm implementing a --help command and I want to show some examples on how to run the app with different commands. This is a template app btw, other apps will reuse this code, some will be self-contained apps others won't be self-contained, that's why I wouldn't like to simply hardcode the name in my examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a dotnet core console app and ran the following code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace TestApp
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName);
    }
  }
}
```

When running `dotnet run` it shows dotnet. I built a standalone version `dotnet publish -c Release -r win10-x64` and it shows TestApp.

I'm not sure how reliable this is though.